# primefaces growl with poll

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I am unsure how to make a growl show up when my poll timer reaches 0. Any ideas on how I can go about implementing this? The showcase only shows how to use growl after pressing a button which does not help me with polls.

Comment: can you post your code pieces please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Disclaimer: 
>   Although this is a "plz send teh codez" question, I will
>   try to show you the direction (after reading [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39412/should-do-it-for-me-questions-be-discouraged)):*

```html
<h:form>
  <p:growl id="messages>
  <p:poll listener="#{myBean.updateGrowl}" update="messages" />
</h:form>
```

And in your bean:

```java
public void updateGrowl() {
 FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
}
```

Comment: Well it may be a plz send teh codez question but I would like to say your answer has helped me.

Comment: ... and I hope it helps the community as well. You are welcome!